# Rails::SourceAnnotationExtractor is not a class/module (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to run my ruby on rails project with version 6 but it does not leave me, I updated it from version 5.2.3 to the most recent one and it sent me that error

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of an internal change in Rails https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32065

Please check what gem are you using that is causing this error? Gems like rspec-rails, haml-rails have released updated versions which fix this issue. Rails codebase will also get a fix for this based on this comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36313#issuecomment-496842892

Comment: thanks, was by don't update the gem 'haml-rails' to the last version